# Can I assemble an Apple labeled hard drive in another laptop?

Tags: hdd

A lot of hard drives delivered with Macs come with an Apple logo.

Is it possible to put those drives in other laptops like Asus, Acer, Toshiba etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Those hard drives are OEM-drives build by Seagate, Toshiba or other hard drive manufacturers for Apple.

Usually there should be no problem to put them in other non-Apple laptops if they fit physically.

You won't be able to mount the HFS-volumes on those drives without special file-system drivers like Paragon's HFS+ for Windows in a dual-bay configuration.

There might be rare cases however, where drives with Apple firmware in conjunction with special SATA- or IDE-controllers used in non-Apple laptops might not work reliably. Without knowledge and special hardware it's almost impossible to detect occurring errors (e.g. bit-errors).

Answer (score 1):

A hard drive is a hard drive.
Basically, if the plugs fit, it will work.

With the caveats that...

- SATA 2 & 3 run at different maximum speeds, 3GB/s & 6GB/s; in a mixed environment you will run at the slowest speed.
- you may need to reformat to be able to use the drive in another machine.
- if it's a Fusion drive Windows won't be able to use it as Fusion; it will see it as 2 separate drives.
- The Mac OS itself, will, of course, not work on a PC.

Comment: We should honor each other for posting almost identical answers at the same time! ;-)

Comment: Duly honoured <grin>

Comment: same here <broad grin>

Answer (score 0):

if it's a normal hdd, no problem with the caveats mentioned above.
If it's a SSD, it'll run, but you might not be able to properly use the garbage collection features of the SSD on e.g. Windows